# Is telerik not supported with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, telerik

I use bootstrap for my website template.
In my web site I have several telerik control, all telerik control work correctly but RadImageEditor is incompatible with bootstrap css.

The file `bootstrap.min.css` is incompatible. When I remove this file my RadImageEditor work correctly.

Comment: What is incompatible? If bootstrap breaks another control this is most likely due to the fact that it uses global selectors (i.e., element selectors) which can break almost anything.

Comment: I know this is old, but Telerik now have a Bootstrap-based skin, give that a try and see how things go: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax-beta/imageeditor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx?skin=Bootstrap